# correct syntax for limit union and order by clause with local variables and randomization in mysql : Error(1221)

Tags: mysql, union, where-clause, random, sql-limit

I am trying to create a random sample (30-70) as below  -:

```
set @total=(select count(*) from tab_1 where predict_var ="4" or predict_var ="2" ) ;
set @sample= (select @total*(70/30))  ;

#@total,@sample
#4090,9543.333331970
```

*# Post this I can fetch the elements via this generic syntax*

```
PREPARE STMT FROM "SELECT * FROM tab_1 where predict_var ='2' or  predict_var ='4' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ? " ;
EXECUTE STMT USING @sample; # **THIS WORKS**
```

**However while taking the union of the two conditions as here, it does not work.** And it looks like the where condition with predict_var ='2' or  predict_var ='4' either with '' or with "" does not work - how do I make it work ?

**My complete use-case is something like this -:**

```
#This logic is my end-goal in retrieval of records
PREPARE STMT FROM " SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE predict_var = '4' or predict_var = '2' ORDER BY RAND() union (SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE predict_var = '0' or predict_var = '1' ORDER BY RAND() limit ?  )"
EXECUTE STMT USING @sample; # **does not work**

# This does not work either and gives "Error(1221) incorrect usage of union and order by
```

I also tried something like this (which I think is very in-efficienet, since this will create temporary table (I could also opt for views, but the point is getting it right)

```
# using temp table/ could also get it via views - but doesn't work,nevertheless
#Alternate logic - but does not work either

PREPARE STMT FROM "SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE predict_var = '0' or predict_var = '1' ORDER BY RAND() limit ? " ; # Works

create table temp
select * from (EXECUTE STMT USING @sample ) ; # Error(1064)

SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE predict_var = '4' or predict_var = '2' ORDER BY  RAND() union select * from temp ; # of course does not work
```

I vaguely understand this is about moving the union & order by clause
Tip :- please expalin why this fails , if possible without suggesting other methods such a concatenate. Related  - http://orkus.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/variable-limit-statement-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I got it !

```
PREPARE STMT FROM " SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE predict_var = '4' or predict_var = '2'  union 
(SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE predict_var = '0' or predict_var = '1' limit ?  ) ORDER BY RAND() " ;
EXECUTE STMT USING @sample; # fetches a total of 13,633 records
```

*The only thing I changed was to remove the **order by** from the 1st query completely and **place it after the combined query** (really that small shuffling around!).  Please nudge if this wouldn't work, randomization wise - or if you have better suggestions.